# List View in Files suddenly uses icons twice as large

Tags: pantheon-files

I was working with files and for some reason all the icons suddenly became about 2X larger, which caused the line spacing to also go up by 2X and now the display is half blank space and much less pleasant to use. This program seems to have no preferences for anything including icon sizes, so how DO I reset it? Running Hera.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind: I eventually tried "ctrl-minus" and it did the trick (learn something new every day ...).

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the icon size using `<Control>Scroll`